# Did I correctly derive the scheme for this PDE using the Crank Nicolson Method?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, numerical-methods

I'm taking an Applied Numerical Methods course this semester, and I was given the following homework problem:

[image]

Basically, before I begin writing any sort of code, I would like to ensure that I have set everything up correctly.

I took the starting PDE and used the Crank-Nicolson method to bring it down to the following:

$$
\frac{u_m^{n+1}-u_m^n}{k} = 0.4\frac{u_{m+1}^{n+1}-2u_{m}^{n+1}+u_{m-1}^{n+1} + u_{m+1}^{n}-2u_{m}^{n}+u_{m-1}^{n}}{2h^2} - 0.2\frac{u_{m+1}^{n+1}-u_{m-1}^{n+1}-u_{m+1}^{n}+u_{m-1}^{n}}{4h} + \frac{u_m^{n+1}+u_m^{n}}{2}
$$

To get this, I took the starting equation (first one on the list in the problem) and shifted focus up by 1/2k (or n + 1/2).  Then, from this point, for the u_t side I took the centered difference and for the other side of the equation I took the averages [(u_m^n+1 + u_m_n) /2].  Then, each of the components on the right hand side had two numerator components.  I took a centered difference of the appropriate derivative of each of these components, recombined the fractions, and obtained my result above.  This is basically me describing the Crank Nicolson method.  I very well may have done something wrong here, so if something seems off please let me know!

Finally, I plugged in h=k=0.001 and separated the n's from the n+1's, and I got

$$
-200.05u_{m-1}^{n+1}+400.9995u_{m}^{n+1}-199.95u_{m+1}^{n+1} = 199.95u_{m-1}^{n}-398.9995u_{m}^{n}+200.05u_{m+1}^{n}
$$

Then, if I'm not mistaken, this formula gives me information on the following points

[image]

Then from here, I just use MATLAB to create a system of 1000 equations with 1000 variables.

The scheme doesn't look too pretty, but at least according to my calculations it is the correct formula for the problem.  I may have missed the mark a bit (or a lot) here, so I'd really appreciate if someone could tell me what they think of my work (both my results ***and*** my method) thus far so I may continue with the problem.

Comment: You forgot the coefficients $0.4$ and $0.2$.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Dang it... I added the coefficients and recalculated my values for my final formula

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the interface of the tridiagonal solver to your question. Essentially, you have to fill the three arrays, and that almost with the same value per array, excepting the first and last entry.

Comment: I think you would benefit by generalizing things.  For example, work with the equation $u_t = D u_{xx} - v u_{x} + u$ instead (don't set $D$ and $v$), and leave $h$ and $k$ as variables.  There are many benefits to this.  1) You can write a more versatile code. 2) You can see more clearly which values affect which coefficients in the discretization. 3) It'll be easier to run error analyses later, which is a necessary numerical tool that involves varying $h$ and $k$. 4) The whole thing will look "prettier," as in, you'll see patterns in the coefficients.

Comment: Note the approximation to the $u_x$ term. It should be a halfsum of
$\frac{u_{m+1} - u_{m-1}}{2h}$ for the $n$-th and $n+1$-st time layer. You have halfdifference instead.

Comment: You have specified equations for the inner points, but not the equations used for the boundary conditions. The RBC is pretty simple, the LBC is more challenging, since it is tricky to approximate it with order $O(h^2)$ like the spatial order of C-N scheme you're using. Finally, if you try to write down your tridiagonal matrix, you'll se that the first and the last equations have coefficients magnitude of about 1, and others have magnitude of about hundreeds. Try to keep all the coefficients about same magnitude, e.g. multiply your scheme by $k$ when converting to linear system.